# Python: group by specific keys in dictionary and the sum of those key values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas-groupby

```
dict_ot={"Berlin":4, "London":3,"Madrid":3,"Germany":51, "Others":1, "France":4}
```

In the above dictionary, I would like to have the following output, adding each together with the total after the `=` sign:

```
Berlin, Germany = 55
Madrid, Others = 4
London =7
```

I will use it for bar chart ...

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you want to use Pandas? You can use Python without any extra libraries for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_ot={"Berlin":4, "London":3,"Madrid":3,"Germany":51, "Others":1, "France":4}
grpBy = [("Germany", "Berlin"), ("Madrid", "Others"), ("London",)]
res = defaultdict(int)
for i in grpBy:
    for j in i:
        res[i] += dict_ot[j]

for k, v in res.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(", ".join(k), v))
```

**Output:**

```
Germany, Berlin: 55
London: 3
Madrid, Others: 4
```

Comment: dict_ot={1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 8: 1, 79: 2}  and I'm getting 'int' object is not iterable. group by a=1,2,3 ; b= 5,8; c=79
and the output should like ot=[8,2,2]

Comment: You cannot have int as key

Comment: @user8195447 you gave an example that's different from the one in your comment. How can you expect people to help you if you're not clear about what you want?